# How does a Django form know where to save its data when not using ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

How does Django know what database table one form relates to, if I don't specify its model using a `ModelForm`? You see, in a form like this:

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

How does Django know it has to save this data in the model X?

For me it's obvious when you use this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Article

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

Comment: The data won't save to a model at all unless you explicitly assign it to one in your view.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Hope this will be helpful to other newbies. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to associate the form with your model at the view. Such as:

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    url = form.cleaned_data['url']
    comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

    my_comment = Comment(name=name,url=url,comment=comment)
    my_comment.save()
```